# VHDL-can't add numbers?

Tags: vhdl

Hello I want to build a clock on my ALTERA DE2 that I can adjust the length of by pressing keys. 
Now the problem is that when I convert from STD_LOGIC_VECTOR to UNSIGNED the code does not work:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; Do not use with numeric_std

entity Adjust_Clock_4_buttens is

port(
    clk,clk1 : in STD_LOGIC;
    minutes_plus, minutes_minus,houres_plus,houres_minus : in STD_LOGIC;

    minutes : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
    houres   : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

    output_minutes : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
    output_houres : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

    LED_0 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    LED_1 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    LED_2 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    LED_3 : OUT STD_LOGIC

);
end entity Adjust_Clock_4_buttens ;

architecture behavioral of Adjust_Clock_4_buttens  is

    signal button1_r : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal button2_r : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
     signal button3_r : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
     signal button4_r : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

--    signal minutes_total  : unsigned(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');
--   signal houres_total  : unsigned(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');

     signal minutes_total  : unsigned(5 downto 0);
     signal houres_total  : unsigned(4 downto 0);

begin

    process(clk)
    begin

        if (rising_edge(clk) )then

                minutes_total<=unsigned(minutes);
                houres_total<=unsigned(houres);   

                 -- Shift the value of button in button_r
            -- The LSB is unused and is there solely for metastability
            button1_r <= button1_r(button1_r'left-1 downto 0) & minutes_plus;
            button2_r <= button2_r(button2_r'left-1 downto 0) & minutes_minus;
                button3_r <= button3_r(button3_r'left-1 downto 0) & houres_plus;                
                button4_r <= button4_r(button4_r'left-1 downto 0) & houres_minus;   


            if button1_r(button1_r'left downto button1_r'left-1) = "01" then -- Button1 rising --button1_r[2:1]
                minutes_total <= (minutes_total + 1);
                     LED_0<='1';LED_1<='0';LED_2<='0';LED_3<='0';

            elsif button2_r(button2_r'left downto button2_r'left-1) = "01" then -- Button2 rising --button1_r[2:1]
               minutes_total <= (minutes_total-1 );
                    LED_0<='0';LED_1<='1';LED_2<='0';LED_3<='0';
            end if;


            if button3_r(button3_r'left downto button3_r'left-1) = "01" then -- Button1 rising --button1_r[2:1]
                houres_total <= (houres_total + 1);
                     LED_0<='0';LED_1<='0';LED_2<='1';LED_3<='0';

            elsif button4_r(button4_r'left downto button4_r'left-1) = "01" then -- Button2 rising --button1_r[2:1]
                houres_total<= (houres_total-1 );
                     LED_0<='0';LED_1<='0';LED_2<='0';LED_3<='1';
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

     output_minutes <= std_logic_vector(minutes_total);
     output_houres <= std_logic_vector(houres_total);

end architecture behavioral ;
```

So in this code I get the time from another block the problem start when I try to add minutes and hours and for some reason it does not react to pressing of the keys. Could anyone explain maybe why is that?

Comment: you should avoid mixing tabs and spaces in your indentations...

Comment: how are you processing the button lines? They need to be "de bounced" to act once per press, or could be seen for thousands of clk pulses and increase the time by that much...

Comment: As you're using the edges that may not be as bad for bounces. But you should check that the shift registers are actually implemented as shift registers after synthesis, as hard shift registers don't fight correctly against metastability (at least in Xilinx parts). And you should better add a reset and starting states to them !?

Comment: Are the LED behaving correctly? And are you on a board or in a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

minutes_total<=unsigned(minutes);
is on 2 lines, inside and outside of the process, which generates multiple line drivers, and will not work, ever!
(didn't read the rest of the code, there may be other problems, like hours not taking an e)

Now that it's inside the process, you need to rename minutes_total as minute_source, else you're incrementing the value only for the one clock cycle when you have a button edge!

Comment: I tried what you said , and i published the wrong code ... I enterd the :     minutes_total<=unsigned(minutes); houres_total<=unsigned(houres); into the process but still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you only have the clock in the sensitivity list of your process. Try adding the buttons in the sensitivity list, since they drive your if conditions. (Not sure if that's the problem but I guess it's worth a try)

Comment: shouldn't matter with this CLK synchronous process!